# Expand/Collapse child elements in a tree (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a newbie in AngularJS and faced with an issue.

Need to create message history tree, which provides expand/collapse functionality on the parent item.

I've created view:

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="appt in apptsToFilter() | filter: groupByAppt" ng-click="showChilds()">
        <span>{{appt.startTime}} - Appt. Id: {{appt.appointmentId}} </span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in appts | filter: {appointmentId: appt.appointmentId}" ng-show="active">
                <span>{{item.message}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is my controoler for this view:

```
function MessageHistoryController($scope, $routeParams, MessageHistoryResource) {
    ......//some code

    $scope.active = false;
    $scope.showChilds = function() {
        if ($scope.active == false) {
            $scope.active = true;
        } else {
            $scope.active = false;
        }
    };
}
```

This is what I get, when I've expanded first parent item:

```
ParentItem2:
   - Child1
   - Child2
   - Child3

ParentItem2
   - Child1
   - Child2

ParentItem3
   - Child1
```

When I click on any parent item - **all** **of my subtrees expanded or collapsed**.

But I expected this result, as below (**only clicked item should be expanded**):

```
ParentItem2:
   - Child1
   - Child2
   - Child3
ParentItem2
ParentItem3
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you have all of your parent, clickable items, set to one boolean. This can be resolved in the HTML without the `active` bool.

1. Set your show/hide element to:

   > `ng-show="appt.active"`
2. Then set your click call to:

   > `ng-click="appt.active = !appt.active"`

**Full Example:**

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="appt in apptsToFilter() | filter: groupByAppt" ng-click="appt.active = !appt.active">
        <span>{{appt.startTime}} - Appt. Id: {{appt.appointmentId}} </span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in appts | filter: {appointmentId: appt.appointmentId}" ng-show="appt.active">
                <span>{{item.message}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Even though `appt.active` would initialize as undefined when clicked it will change to true, at least it does on my end and this is how I handle these cases.

You could also loop through the `appt` and define active in the javascript.

---

For future reference you can simplify your `$scope.showChilds` function to:

```
$scope.showChilds = function () {
    $scope.active = !$scope.active
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. only need collapse icon for professional answer <span  ng-show="appt.active">-</span>  <span  ng-show="!(appt.active)">+</span> better is move ng-click on collapse icon because childs click